# Gutenberg work with Bootstrap Shortcodes plugin

Tags: editor, block-editor

We are using now classic editor with the Bootstrap Shortcodes plugin. So after moving to WordPress 5, how this Bootstrap Shortcodes plugin work with Gutenberg editor.

After upgrade to WordPress 5 existing design with bootstrap will collapse?

https://wordpress.org/plugins/bootstrap-3-shortcodes/

Comment: The best way to find out is to copy your site onto a staging server and try it out for yourself. Second best is checking the plugin's documentation to see whether they mention compatibility or issues. Third best - ask the plugin authors directly. :)

Comment: Yeah, I did all mentioned options and no-reply from author. Just I curious anyone got any solution.

Comment: I found a temp solution. https://github.com/gnanasekaranl/Bootstrap-Shortcode-in-Gutenberg